# What-s the measure of the $\angle BAC$ in the triangle isosceles below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure below $AB=AC$ and $P$ is the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$. It is also known that $AD=BC$. Calculate the measure of angle $BAC$ (Answer:$20^o$)

[image]

Progress I found

$\alpha = \frac{\angle BAC}{2}$

M is the midpoint of

$BC = 2x \Leftrightarrow BM = x\\
R=PA=PB=PC\\
\triangle PMC:R(sen(2\alpha)=x\\
\triangle APD: \frac{2x}{sen2\alpha}=\frac{R}{sen (180-3\alpha)}= \frac{R}{sen(3\alpha)}=\frac{x}{sen(2\alpha)sen(3\alpha}\implies\\
sen(3\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}=sen30^o \\
\therefore \angle BAC = 20^o$

Does anyone have a resolution by geometry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy $\triangle BPC$, and add a point $O$ on the left side of $AD$ such that $\triangle DOA\cong \triangle BPC$.

Using the same notation as the question,

$$\angle DOA = \angle BPC = 4\alpha$$

As opposite angles at point $P$,

$$\angle DPA = \angle BPM = 2\alpha$$

As $OD=OA = R$, and with $\angle DOA = 2\angle DPA$, a circle centred at $O$ through $D$ and $A$ would pass through $P$, so

$$OP=OA=R = AP\\
\angle POA = 60^\circ$$

On the other hand, $\angle POD = 2\angle PAD = 2\alpha$, so

$$\begin{align*}
\angle POD + \angle DOA &= \angle POA\\
2\alpha + 4\alpha &= 60^\circ\\
\angle BAC = 2\alpha &= 20^\circ
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the original proof in the question, which uses the sine laws. But **are the sine laws not geometry?** The sine laws may be proven using altitudes of the triangle, so:

Consider $\triangle APD$. Drop an altitude from $A$ onto the extended line $PD$, and let the foot be $N$.

$$\begin{align*}\triangle ANP &= 90^\circ\\
AP&= BP = R\\
\angle APN &= \angle BPM = 2\alpha\\
\triangle ANP &\cong \triangle BMP &&\text{(AAS)}
\end{align*}$$

$AN=BM=x = \frac12 AD$, so $\triangle AND$ is a $60-90-30$ triangle.

As an external angle of $\triangle APD$,

$$\angle NDA = \alpha + 2\alpha = 30^\circ\\
\angle BAC = 2\alpha = 20^\circ$$

Comment: Yes, it would be geometry but maybe I expressed myself wrong... The resolution uses trigonometry concepts and my idea was exactly the way you posted